# Getting error when using and or statement in my expression?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, report

I am trying to do an and/or statement for a field in my report, and I am getting an error. If I just do the one without the "or" is works fine. Is there a different way I need to code this?

```
=IIf(Fields!NOP.Value = "1","Consulting Fee","") or IIf(Fields!NOP.Value = "3","Honoraria","")
```

Comment: this is for a report viewer/report.rdlc in asp.net website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested `IIF` statements should work:

```
=IIF(Fields!NOP.Value = "1", "Consulting Fee", IIF(Fields!NOP.Value = "3", "Honoraria", ""))
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I've been able to tell there is no formal "OR" statement in SSRS expressions, what you might try is a switch:

```
=Switch(Fields!NOP.Value = "1", "Consulting Fee", Fields!NOP.Value = "3","Honoraria")
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to like that "Omitted argument cannot match a Paramarray parameter

Comment: Looks like I got carried away with the commas, there should be no ending comma, I'll edit the answer to fix that.  Also take a look at [link]http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ChrisAlbrektson/bidn-blog/1478/ssrs-switch-function-examples or [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx for more references on expression syntax, switches in particular.

Comment: @nodonoghue In your defense, the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) example has a trailing comma - I didn't find on that specific page why it was included.